# Mac: Getting path of current desktop picture from terminal

Tags: macos, osascript, desktop-background

I'm writing a bash script that takes care of setting the desktop background on my mac. I can set the desktop background with:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid White.png"'
```

However, I also need to GET the path of the desktop picture. The closest I've gotten is:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to get desktop picture'
```

This returns the path of the desktop picture but in a really weird format that I can't use:

```
document file Solid White.png of folder Solid Colors of folder Desktop Pictures of folder Library of startup disk
```

Is there any way I can get the path of the current desktop picture that would return:

```
/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Solid\ Colors/Solid\ White.png
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
osascript -e '
    tell application "Finder"
    set theDesktopPic to desktop picture as alias
    set theName to posix path of theDesktopPic
    end tell'

/Users/mark/Documents/Carbon fibre.png
```

Comment: Does not work on macOS Mojave (Public Beta 5). Gives `Can’t make missing value into type alias.`

Comment: do you think you can write than in JXA too?

Answer (score 6):

I found that the answer can be shortened to one line:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "finder" to get posix path of (get desktop picture as alias)'
```

Comment: On Sierra, this gives an error: 63:68: execution error: Can’t make missing value into type alias. (-1700)

Comment: On Mojave it gives me `63:68: execution error: Not authorized to send Apple events to Finder. (-1743)`

Comment: Works like a charm when executing from iterm with zsh on Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me under MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 using both Script Editor and `osascript`:

```
tell application "System Events" to get pictures folder of every desktop
```

Output:

```
{"/Users/jchilders/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Wallpapers"}
```

Replace `every` with `first` to get a single entry:

```
tell application "System Events" to get pictures folder of first desktop
```

Output:

```
"/Users/jchilders/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Wallpapers"
```

Original answer from apple.stackexchange.com [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151435/how-to-programmatically-get-the-path-to-the-wallpaper-on-the-active-desktop).